# Is there any account deletion option on Stack Apps

Tags: support

When I log in to stack apps to post a question via some website (gmail or facebook),after that it shows logged in so I have to click "log out" from its meta,Can you put a delete option there on my stack apps profile made recently?

Comment: so what exactly do you want? Do u want to delete the "Stack Apps" a/c? If yes, then all you have do is "click on the profile picture" top-bar and then click on the 'delete' tab link.

Comment: Since you've posted there, you can't use the instant self deletion feature. You'll need to [contact us](http://stackapps.com/contact) and request deletion.

Comment: @animuson To be precise, a _single_ post [still allows self-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979) (I verified it experimentally, many times).